# How to use entitymanager created using jnidi lookup in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, entitymanager

I am falling short of answers to this question, I am forced to go back to a way of using XMLs.

I have my application already working fine with Spring framework. I am trying to move it to Spring boot. I have following `persistence.xml`:

```
<persistence version="2.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
                        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="primarybasic">
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mayur</jta-data-source>
        <properties>

            <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" 
                      value="java:jboss/eightseventythree/persistencebasic" />

            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false" />
        </properties>

    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

and this in my `applicationcontext.xml`:

```
<jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="java:jboss/eightseventythree/persistencebasic" id="entityManagerFactory"
                     expected-type="javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="entityManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.SharedEntityManagerBean">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>
```

I understood how to make use of JNDI datasource in spring boot (ie. via application.properties). But I am not able to find a way to use JNDI entitymanagerFactory in Spring Boot. (I am using JBOSS and datasource is already configured in standalone.xml).

Can somebody please give some pointers.

Comment: Just do tje jndi lookup in a `@Bean` annotated method, it isn't any different then the xml version...

Comment: but does that mean i still have to use persistence .xml to register  entitymanagerfactory?      your solution just gets rid of applicationContext.xml

Comment: and also, u can add jndi bound data source to application properties, but not jndi entitymangerfactory why? at the end of the day both returns the object of respected type ready to inject in application code.

Comment: The `persistence.xml` is for bootstrapping/configuring the `EntityManagerFactory` if you remove that nothing will be registered in JNDI.